# How can I reuse an instance of a webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, class-design

I am running a service **A** which has a class **X**. I am going to deploy another service **B** on same machine which is using this class **X**. How can I make sure that the same instance of service **A** is reused instead of another.

PS:Service written in JAVA.

Adding: Both these services are Axis2 services. Service B is hot-deployed. Service B used class Y which is extension of class X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could we try to distinguish classes, objects and services.

You have something like this?

```
@javax.jws.WebService
public class ServiceAAA{

    public String echo(String arg) {
        // some really nice code here     
    }

}
```

and you want to add

```
@javax.jws.WebService
public class ServiceBBB{
    public String superEcho(String arg) {
        // even more code here
        // which needs to reuse the code from A's echo()     
    }   
}
```

So clearly we don't want to cut and paste between the two implementations. How do we reuse?

Alternative 1:

Directly call A from B. You are asking how to do that. It could be done. You would just code a JAX-WS client call in your implmentation. However I stringly recommend against this. A service call is likely to be more expensive than a simple Java call.

Only do this if y6ou don't have the option of deploying the two service classes together.

Alternative 2:

Refactor the implementation. Just move the code into a worker class.

@javax.jws.WebService
    public class ServiceAAA{

```
    MyWorker worker = new Worker();
    public String echo(String arg) {
        return worker.doSomething(arg) ;      
    }

}
```

@javax.jws.WebService
    public class ServiceBBB{

```
    MyWorker worker = new Worker();
    public String superEcho(String arg) {
        worker.doSomething(arg) ;  
        // and some morestuff             
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! 
I want to call A from B. Objective here is to use the same code base and infrastructure i.e - Reuse already running instance.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I'll amend my answer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that A uses an object of class X, and B too.

Configure your two webServices A and B to use the same instance of object X.
This configuration could be done by several means, for example:

- in your starting sequence, create an instance X and assign it via `setX(x)` to each webService.
- or you could do this in a Constructor, using static fields

Example:

```
     @javax.jws.WebService
     public class A implements WebService {
       public static final X x = new X();

       public void methodA() {
         // use x
       }
     }

     @javax.jws.WebService
     public class B implements WebService {
       private Y y = new Y(A.x);

       public void methodB() {
         // use y that uses x.
         y.methodY();
       }
     }

     public class Y {
       private final X x;
       public Y(X x) {
         this.x = x;
       }

       public void methodY() {
         // use x, it is the same instance as in A
       }
     }
```

Comment: Its 2 - service A uses object of class X.
What do you mean by starting sequence? Both these services are Axis2 services. Service B is hot-deployed. Service B used class Y which is extension of class X.

Comment: @Ankit "starting sequence" is a code that you run when your application is starting. Very often, you have a place like this, where you execute the code that is needed only once ...

Comment: @Ankit If Y (used by B) is a subclass of X (used by A), how could they be the same instance? I don't understand...

Comment: @KLE Y uses an instance of X. I want it to reuse the existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know java, but you could make use of a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) on the objects your are trying to use.

edit: I think you should have class X implementing the singleton pattern...